# Show SVProgressHUD on ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swift3

I used the web Service in AppDelegate. But i want to show the SVProgressHUD on the initial view controller (View Controller), And when the Web Service completed then hide the SVProgressHUD in View Controller.

Comment: can you show the code of appdelegate

Comment: Ok no problem, call the [SVProgressHUD show]; before the API call and dismiss (use main thread) after getting the response

Comment: -(void)GetCountryList
{
     [SVProgressHUD show];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [SVProgressHUD show];
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BaseUrl,Service_ListOfCountry];
        NSDictionary *dicCountry = [WebServiceHelper GetDataFromServer:urlString];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
           
            [SVProgressHUD show];
            if ([[dicCountry valueForKey:@"msg"] isEqualToString:@"success"]){
}
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        });
    });
}
I used this, but not show.

Comment: This is your appdelegate code right??

Comment: Yes, I used this code in App Delegate.

Comment: @ Hari Mohan, I executed your code and it's working fine. Just cross check your code

Comment: Actually I used ScrollView in View Controller.so Can be a problem.

Comment: ya, right this could be the possibilities

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    [self SetUpView];
}


-(void)SetUpView
{
    BtnStart.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    BtnStart.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.title = @"Home";
    MyScrollV.scrollEnabled=YES;
    MyScrollV.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    if (IS_IPHONE_4) {
        
        MyScrollV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0,590);
    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_5){
        
        MyScrollV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height+160);
    }
   }

Comment: This is my view Controller Code. Can you help me, how can i show the SVProgressHUD.

Answer (score 2):

There is a static method on `SVProgressHUD` called

`+ (void)setContainerView:(UIView*)containerView;`

```
[SVProgressHUD setContainerView:yourViewController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your demand, my suggestion is to package two 
class,`HUD` and `Mysevers`:

I have token example here:

`HUD.m`：

```
#import "HUD.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@implementation HUD


 +(void)addHUD
{
    MBProgressHUD*  HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, IPHONE_WIDTH, IPHONE_HEIGHT)];

    HUD.tag = 5000;
    HUD.labelText = @"正在加载";

    [WINDOW addSubview:HUD];
    [HUD show:YES];
}

+(void)removeHUD
{
    MBProgressHUD*  HUD = (MBProgressHUD*)[WINDOW viewWithTag:5000];
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];

    HUD = nil;

}

@end
```

`Mysevers.m`:

```
#import "Mysevers.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "HUD.h"

@implementation Mysevers

+(void)AFPOSTAddressname:(NSString*)addressName parmas:(NSDictionary*)parmas RequestSuccess:(void(^)(id result))success failBlcok:(void(^)(void))failBlcok{

 [HUD addHUD];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *requestManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASE_URL,addressName];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlStr);

/*[requestManager POST:urlStr parameters:parmas success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    [HUD removeHUD];
    success(responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error==%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    [HUD removeHUD];
    failBlcok();
}];*/

[requestManager POST:urlStr parameters:parmas progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    [HUD removeHUD];
    success(responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"error==%@",[error localizedDescription]);
        [HUD removeHUD];
        failBlcok();
    }


    return ;
}];


}


  +(void)AFGETAddressname:(NSString*)addressName parmas:(NSDictionary*)parmas RequestSuccess:(void(^)(id result))success failBlcok:(void(^)(void))failBlcok{
    [HUD addHUD];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *requestManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASE_URL,addressName];

NSLog(@"%@",urlStr);


/*[requestManager GET:urlStr parameters:parmas success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

    [HUD removeHUD];
    success(responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error==%@",[error localizedDescription]);

    [HUD removeHUD];
    failBlcok();
}];*/

[requestManager GET:urlStr parameters:parmas progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    [HUD removeHUD];
    success(responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"error==%@",[error localizedDescription]);

    [HUD removeHUD];
    failBlcok();
}];



}
@end
```

**USAGE**

You can have a test in your project:

```
[Mysevers AFPOSTAddressname:url parmas:params RequestSuccess:^(id result) {
   // code here
}
```

Hope this can help you, this is my experience.And if you want to use `SVProgressHUD`, you can also replace the `MBProgressHUD`.

Comment: Try this HUD library for iOS in swift https://github.com/shubh10/JustHUD